# Rounding off to greater than 0.9 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to round off a number i.e if its 2.3 and greater it should stay as 2 but if greater than 2.9 it should round off to 3. Not sure how i would make them work with Math.round as this always makes it to 3 after 2.4. Thanks.

Comment: Greater than 2.9 or greater or greater than or equal to 2.9? Also, I doubt that Math.round rounds 2.41 up to 3.

Comment: Greater than 2.9 should become to 3 but if less than that it should be 2

Comment: You can make custom function that can implement this logic and instead of Math.round u can call this function. function customRound(a){ if(a*10%10 >= 3 && a*10%10 <=9) { return a - (a%10); } else { return a + (10 - a%10); } };

Comment: What about 2.9 itself?

Comment: 2.9 should also become to 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to add an offset to shift the rounding "pivot" from 0.5 to 0.9. If `x` is the number to round then use

`Math.round(x - 0.4)`

Comment: This is correct answer, don't know, why there are downvoter(s). There is no need to use custom round function, as is shown in other answers, but its enough like in your answer.

Comment: You already know that you made a typo that made the code not work correctly. Now that you fixed the typo the downvotes were reversed. The system works.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a helper method like below

```
function Extended_Roundoff(num, decimal_threshold){
  var decimal_part = num - Math.floor(num);
  if(decimal_part >= decimal_threshold){
    return Math.ceil(num);
  }else{
    return Math.floor(num);
  }
}

console.log(Extended_Roundoff(2.3, 0.9));
console.log(Extended_Roundoff(2.95, 0.9));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function customRound(v) {
  return Math.round(v-0.4);
};
```

if v is great less than x.9, it returns x

```
customRound(2.1) // 2
customRound(2.8) // 2
customRound(2.89) // 2
```

else if v is great than x.9, it retuans x+1

```
customRound(2.91) // 3
```

And you can custom the offset as you like.

Comment: UV'd. Essentially my answer but with some explanations. (Although personally I wouldn't wrap into a separate function - to me the behaviour of `Math.round(v - 0.4)` is more obvious at the call site than `customRound(v) )`

Answer (score 0):

This will return 24 and if num is 23.6 will return 23

```
var num = 23.9;
var nr = num % Math.floor(num)
nr = Math.round(nr * 100) / 100
if(nr >=0.9){
    num = Math.floor(num+1);
}else{
    num = Math.floor(num);
}
alert(num);
```

Answer (score -1):

Didn't quite catch first condition: if it is 2.3 and **greater**(?) it should return 2.

So here is function, that rounds numbers with fraction > 0.9

```
function customRound(number){
  return (number-(~~number))>0.9 ? ~~number+1 : ~~number;
}
```

Comment: if it is any less than 2.9 then it should round off to 2 and if 2.9 or any greater than this it should become 3. Thanks

Comment: what should become 7.9?